# Clip objects drawn outside of canvas

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I clip objects drawn outside a canvas? In the following, the black square represents the boundary of the canvas. I do not want the left half the circle to be drawn because it is outside the canvas:

[image]

This is simple example, but I am drawing PNGs and SVGs inside a canvas with various transformations applied to them, and I need a solution that would clip the portion drawn outside the canvas.

Here is the code for the above:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          child: CustomPaint(
            child: Container(),
            painter: CanvasPainter(),
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CanvasPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
        Paint()
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..color = Colors.black);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0.0, 100.0);
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(0, 0), 50.0, Paint()..color = Colors.blue);
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Comment: this can be helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59626727/how-to-erase-clip-from-canvas-custompaint

Comment: I had seen that, but it didn't seem to related to clipping objects drawn outside the canvas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to add
`canvas.clipRect(rect);`
so your code be like that:

```
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    canvas.drawRect(
        rect,
        Paint()
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..color = Colors.black);
    canvas.clipRect(rect);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0.0, 100.0);
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(0, 0), 50.0, Paint()..color = Colors.blue);
    canvas.restore();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I saw that API just after posting this question.

Answer (score 4):

To prevent a widget to draw beyond its layout size,  use [ClipRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html) to clip it. For rounded rect shape use [ClipRRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html) and [ClipPath](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html) for custom shape.

```dart
ClipRect(
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            child: CustomPaint(
              child: Container(),   
              painter: CanvasPainter(),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

You can also use it before `CustomPaint`.

I asked a similar question and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69530725/10157127) also solve for this case, and I'm just repeating it here.

Comment: Thanks, that also works. The Canvas API is better for my scenario.